# Equation for all frequent itemsets

Tags: self-study, data-mining, database, frequent-itemsets

> Consider that the database has only three transactions {<a1,a2,...,a100>,
> <a1,a2,...,a50>, <a1,2,...,a25>}. Suppose min_sup = 2. Give the equation for all
> frequent itemsets. Also list all the closed and maximal frequent item sets.

I didn't understand what is meant by 'equation'. I answered that itemsets have to contain support greater than or equal to the minimum support, but my professor said that it was not what he expected.
Can anyone help me to understand: what is the equation for all frequent itemsets?

Comment: You gave the definition of the term. Your professor wants you to apply that definition to this example data to show which item sets are frequent.

Comment: Can you give example